# Test file doesnt detect updated method in source class

Tags: java, testing, netbeans

Im having this problem in Netbeans 15. Im using JDK 17 from OpenJDK. I've configured a web project with *Source Packages* and *Test Packages*.Im using Ant for this project. It runs with Tomcat 9. Usual stuff for me is changing source code and hot reloading it in the Tomcat server which it works fine. No problems upto here.

Recently, I tried to change a class constructor and it compiles perfectly fine. Here goes a similar class example for context.

```
package com;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ClassA extends ClassAAbstract{


    /**
     * Creates a new instance of ClassA
     */
    public ClassA(HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        super(request);
    }

    public ClassA(HttpServletRequest request, String id) throws SQLException {
        super(request, id);
    }

    public ClassA(String str1, String str2, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        super(str1, str2, conn);
    }

}
```

Buuut... when I wanted to create the class test I've encountered this problem. Similar test class for context:

```
package com;

import Types.DatabaseDependableTest;
import com.ClassA;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ClassATest extends DatabaseDependableTest {

    public ClassATest () {
        super();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {
        new ClassA("", "", this.conn); -> error

    }

}
```

The error shown shows the following:

*no suitable constructor found for ClassA(String,String,Connection) constructor com.ClassA(HttpServletRequest) is not applicable*

It suggests using the other two constructors. Any guesses on what might be happening?

I've tried:

1. Closing and reopening the project.
2. Deleting NetBeans project folder and opening it again
3. Deleted cache and tried both options again.

It's worth mentioning that I have a copy of this environment ( A previous version. Same components though, JDK 17, Tomcat 9...) and the tests there work perfectly fine when I update a class method in the source code.

**Edit 1**

I made progress and found out the following.

If I have a package A and classes A1,A2,A3 inside of it, the tests in Test Packages wont recognize any further updates, for these classes, since its initial configuration.

Example:

```
package A;

class A {
    public A(String str){
    }
}
```

A test like the following **WILL** work:

```
package Test;

class ATest {
    public ATest (){
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test(){
        new A("STRING");
    }

}
```

If I add a new constructor to class A then I wont be able to use in the test.

```
package A;

class A {
    public A(String str){
    }
    public A(String str,String str2){ -> New constructor
    }
}
```

A test like the following **WILL NOT** work:

```
package Test;

class ATest {
    public ATest (){
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test(){
        new A("STRING","STRING"); -> error ( constructor A in...)
    }
}
```

Whereas, if I create a new class inside package A, lets say, ANewClass well then I can create a compilable test and change its code as it will be taken into account in the test being made.

```
package A;

class ANewClass  {
    public ANewClass (String str){
    }
    public ANewClass (String str,String str2){
    }
}
```

A test like the following **WILL** work:

```
package Test;

class ATest {
    public ATest (){
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test(){
        new ANewClass("STRING");
        new ANewClass("STRING","STRING");
    // Both OK!
    }
}
```

Im guessing there might be a problem with the classpath or some cached build somewhere.

**Edit 2**

As I also deploy this code to Tomcat using the Netbeans integration, I checked and, effectively, the code works while deployed. The problem is specifically in the tests packages or related to it.

**Solution**

I had a library/jar that had the same classes so I guess it must have been overriding the source code implementation, which I think its wrong since *.class* files should be priority over libs. Anyway, since the code was the same as the jar, I removed it and work well.

Comment: Where does ARPprofile come from? What is ARProfile.ARProfile?

Comment: My mistake, it would actually be com.ClassA to keep it consistent with the example I left.

Comment: Not sure by just looking at it. Could you create a complete, (non-)compilabe example?

Comment: Sure, what else should I add to the example? I mean, the problem is with the actual opened project I have on my PC. If I try to open a new one it works fine. I think its worth mentioning this is an Ant based project.

Comment: I've made some progress. I detailed it in the post.

Comment: Found the problem. I had a library/jar that had the same classes so I guess it must have been overriding the source code implementation, which I think its wrong since .class files should be priority over libs. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Duplicate resources would usually be resolved by the first hit. That means the sequence on the classpath matters. But you should not have duplicate classes, especially not those that you develop yourself. So the removal sounds as the real fix.

Answer (score 0):

There was a duplicate resource that was overriding the one being updated. Specifically a jar containing sources which were also present in the Source Packages and was being loaded first, not taking into account the last one. Removing the JAR file fixed the problem.